# How to align form fileds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms

I've built a form in php which has a bit of JavaScript code. I have mentor 1 in php and then mentor 2 onwards is in JavaScript. I want mentor 2 fileds to have same layout as mentor 1.

Here's the code:

```
      <div class="container">
            <div id="id_of_div_to_hide" class="form-group col-md-6" style="display: none">
            </br></br>
             <div class="container">
             <div class=”row”>    
            <h1>Mentor #1</h1>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="lengthinresearch">Length of time in Research</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lengthinreseasrch" name="lengthinresearch" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <p><b>Type of Research</b></p>
               <input type="checkbox" name="basic" value="basic">
                <label for="basic">Basic</label><br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="clinical" value="clinical">
               <label for="clinical">Clinical</label><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="researchinstitution">Research Institution</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="researchinstitution" name="researchinstitution" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="researchmentor">Research Mentor</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="researchmentor" name="researchmentor" required>
            </div>
        </div>
             </div>
        .
            <div class="container">
            <h1>Mentor's Contact Information</h1>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mentorsphone1">Mentor's Phone </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mentorsphone1"  name="mentorsphone1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="mentorsemail1">Mentor's Email </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mentorsemail1"  name="mentorsemail1" required>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="describeresearch1">Describe your research in 1-2 sentences </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="describeresearch1"  name="describeresearch1" maxlength="50" required>
            
            </div>
            </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="addSite()">Add Mentor</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="removeSite()">Remove Mentor</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_sites">
<script>
   function addSite() {
    
   var new_total_sites = parseInt($('#total_sites').val()) + 1;
 if ($('#total_sites').val() >= 4) {
$('button:contains("Add Mentor")').prop('disabled', true);
 }
   
   var new_label= "<label id='new_label9_" + new_total_sites
                + "'><h1>Mentor #"+ new_total_sites +"</h1></label><br>";
   var new_site_label =
             " <div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><label id='new_label1_'" + new_total_sites
                       + "'>Length of Time in Research: </label></div></div></div>";
   var new_site_input = "<div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><input id='new_site_"
                + new_total_sites
                + "' type='text' class='form-control' list='sites' name='time[]'></div></div></div>";
   var new_slot_label = "<div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><label id='new_label2_ " + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Institution</label></div></div></div>";
   var new_slot_input = "<div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><input class='form-control' id='new_slot_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='institution[]'></div></div></div>";
  var new_research_label = "<div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><label id='new_label3_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Mentor</label></div></div></div>";
   var new_research_input = "<div class='form-row'><div class='container'> <div class='form-group col-md-6'><input class='form-control' id='new_research_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='mentor[]'></div></div></div>";
   var new_form_group_label= "<label id='new_label4_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Type of Research</label><br>";
   var new_basic_label = "<input type='checkbox' name='basic1[]' id='checkbox1" + new_total_sites +"' value='basic'><label for='basic' id='basic"+ new_total_sites +"'>Basic</label></br>";
   var new_clinical_label = "<input type='checkbox' name='basic1[]' id='checkbox2" + new_total_sites +"' value='clinical'><label for='basic' id='basic"+ new_total_sites +"'>Clinical</label></br>"
   var new_form_label= "<label id='new_label5_" + new_total_sites
                + "'><h1>Mentor's Contact Information</h1></label>";
   var new_mentor_label = "<label id='new_label6_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Mentor's Phone</label>";
   var new_mentor_input = "<input class='form-control col-md-6' id='new_mentor_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='phone[]'></br>";
   var new_mentoremail_label ="<label id='new_label7_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Mentor's Email</label>";
    var new_mentoremail_input = "<input class='form-control col-md-6' id='new_mentoremail_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='email[]'></br>";
    var new_describeresearch_label = "<label id='new_label8_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Describe your research</label></div>";
    var new_describeresearch_input = "<input class='form-control col-md-6' id='new_describeresearch_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='describeresearch[]'></br></div></div>";

   $('#new_site').append(new_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_site_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_site_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_form_group_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_basic_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_clinical_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_form_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentor_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentor_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentoremail_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentoremail_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_describeresearch_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_describeresearch_input);
   
   

   $('#total_sites').val(new_total_sites)
 }


function removeSite() {
   var last_total_site = $('#total_sites').val();
   if (last_total_site > 1) {
         $('#new_label9_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label1_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_site_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label2_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_slot_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label3_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_research_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label4_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#basic' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#clinical' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox1' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox2' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label5_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label6_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_mentor_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label7_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_mentoremail_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label8_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_describeresearch_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         
        $('#total_sites').val(last_total_site - 1);
   }
}

   </script>
```

I'm very new to JavaScript. I want the mentor 2 onwards should have same look as mentor 1. Right now mentor 2 onwards has fields below each other. I want them to be one beside another like two fileds on one line and other two fileds on other as mentor 1.

Comment: I have to ask, what are you trying to do here? I haven't seen anyone generate HITML with  Javascript like this in... 15 years? I can see where the immediate issue is but I would much rather help you go in the direction of modern web development instead of helping debug this code...

Comment: Okay, could you please help how to do that?

Comment: I although I agree with Mike and that kind of code makes me personally cringe, I'm also a "get it working and then improve it" kind of person. That said, when it comes to anything appearance-related, instead of JavaScript your first tools should always be CSS and HTML/DOM. You are making HTML/DOM right now, so you should make sure that your classes align with the stylesheet, and that you are injecting your new HTML at the right spot. So inspect the unaltered DOM, find the various selectors, and make sure that they work in your updated DOM, possibly by changing some classes.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I’d research how to create and use a template in javascript. I do it all the time at work, but don’t have access to the code. As a start, google `<script type="text/template">`. You can wrap your template html in these and then use javascript to loop and populate values. You could also probably use the `<template>` tag.